# Options for interacting with an alert for signing in through an in-app browser on iOS

Tags: detox

We ran into a issue where, after adding a functionality for authentication through an in-app web browser, a new confirmation alert appears in the app, that cannot be targeted by Detox. This alert is at this moment seemingly impossible to handle, since there are no preferences that can be added at the setup of the test.

[image]

We actually bypass the entire authentication process once we get into the web browser, but we need to open it in order to call the service and validate that the user that tries to login has the necessary permissions. Also, mocking is not an option, since we use different users between the tests (for testing various feature flags) and that would mean rebuilding the release app for each separate user (at least, that's how I understand the mocking mechanism works). We also tried to tap by coordinates, but Detox validates that there is no system alert present before tapping, which is kind of ironic and funny considering what we are trying to do.

Are there any options for interacting with this popup?